# Tuple to parameter pack

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

This below code from user Faheem Mitha, is based on user Johannes Schaub - litb's answer in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9288547/1655492). This code perfectly does what I seek, which is conversion of a `tuple` into parameter pack, but I don't understand this code well enough and therefore I thought I will create a new discussion that might help template metaprogramming newbies like me. So, please pardon the duplicate posting.

Now moving onto the code

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

template<int ...> struct seq {};

template<int N, int ...S> struct gens : gens<N - 1, N - 1, S...> { };

template<int ...S> struct gens<0, S...>{ typedef seq<S...> type; };

double foo(int x, float y, double z)
{
    return x + y + z;
}

template <typename ...Args>
struct save_it_for_later
{
    std::tuple<Args...> params;
    double(*func)(Args...);

    double delayed_dispatch()
    {
        return callFunc(typename gens<sizeof...(Args)>::type()); // Item #1
    }

    template<int ...S>
    double callFunc(seq<S...>)
    {
        return func(std::get<S>(params) ...);
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    std::tuple<int, float, double> t = std::make_tuple(1, (float)1.2, 5);
    save_it_for_later<int, float, double> saved = { t, foo };
    cout << saved.delayed_dispatch() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I'm completely confounded by Item #1 above:

- What purpose does `typename` serve on that line?
- I understand that `gens<sizeof...(Args)>::type()` will expand to `gens<3>::type()`, but that doesn't seem to match neither `template<int N, int ...S> struct gens : gens<N - 1, N - 1, S...> { };` nor `template<int ...S> struct gens<0, S...>`. I'm obviously missing the point and I'd be glad if someone can explain what is happening here.

I do understand that `callFunc` gets invoked in this form `callFunc(seq<0,1,2>)` and the return statement of this method itself expands to `return func(std::get<0>(params), std::get<1>(params), std::get<2>(params)` and this is what makes this scheme work, but I cannot workout how this `seq<0,1,2>` type is generated.

Note: Using `std::index_sequence_for` is not an option, my compiler doesn't support C++14 features.

PS: Can this technique be classified as template metaprogramming?

Comment: 1) To inform the compiler that `gens<sizeof...(Args)>::type` is a type, and not, say, a member function. 2) parameter packs can be empty.

Comment: `gens<3>` does too match `template<int N, int ...S> struct gens`, with `N==3` and `S` being an empty pack.

Comment: Basically, `seq` is [`std::index_sequence`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) and `gens` is `std::make_index_sequence`

Comment: @T.C. Why would the compiler need that hint? I mean how can it possibly confuse the expression `gens<sizeof...(Args)>::type()` for anything but a `seq<S...>()` constructor call ?

Comment: When you can use _C++17_ this should collapse to `std::apply()` from `<tuple>`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Let's look at what happens here:

```
template<int N, int ...S> struct gens : gens<N - 1, N - 1, S...> { };

template<int ...S> struct gens<0, S...>{ typedef seq<S...> type; };
```

The first one is a generic template, the second one is a specialization that applies when the first template parameter is 0.

Now, take a piece of paper and pencil, and write down how

```
 gens<3>
```

gets defined by the above template. If your answer was:

```
 struct gens<3> : public gens<2, 2>
```

then you were right. That's how the first template gets expanded when `N` is "3", and `...S` is empty. `gens<N - 1, N - 1, S...>`, therefore, becomes `gens<2, 2>`.

Now, let's keep going, and see how `gens<2, 2>` gets defined:

```
 struct gens<2, 2> : public gens<1, 1, 2>
```

Here, in the template expansion, `N` is 2, and `...S` is "2". Now, let's take the next step, and see how `gens<1, 1, 2>` is defined:

```
 struct gens<1, 1, 2> : public gens<0, 0, 1, 2>
```

Ok, now how does `gens<0, 0, 1, 2>` gets defined? It can now be defined by the specialization:

```
 template<int ...S> struct gens<0, S...>{ typedef seq<S...> type; };
```

So, what happens with `struct gens<0, 0, 1, 2>` here? Well, in the specialization, "S..." becomes "0, 1, 2", so this becomes, in a manner of speaking:

```
 struct gens<0, 0, 1, 2> {

   typedef seq<0, 1, 2> type;

 }
```

Now, keep in mind that all of these publicly inherit from each other, "elephant-style", so:

```
 gens<3>::type
```

ends up being a typedef declaration for

```
 struct seq<0, 1, 2>
```

And this is used, by the code that follows to convert the tuple into a parameter pack, using another template:

```
double delayed_dispatch()
{
    return callFunc(typename gens<sizeof...(Args)>::type()); // Item #1
}
```

`...Args` are the tuple parameters. So, if there are three elements in the tuple, `sizeof(...Args)` is 3, and as I've explained above, `gens<sizeof...(Args)>::type()` becomes `gens<3>::type()`, a.k.a. `seq<0, 1, 2>()`.

So, now:

```
template<int ...S>
double callFunc(seq<S...>)
{
    return func(std::get<S>(params) ...);
}
```

The `S...` part becomes "0, 1, 2", so the

```
std::get<S>(params)...
```

Becomes a parameter pack that gets expanded to:

```
std::get<0>(params), std::get<1>(params), std::get<2>(params),
```

And that's how a tuple becomes a parameter pack.

Answer (score 3):

With C++17 you can use "if constexpr" to create a sequence wrapper:

```
template <int indxMax, template <int... > class spack, int ... seq>
constexpr auto get_seq17()
{
    static_assert(indxMax >= 0, "Sequence size must be equal to or greater than 0!");
    if constexpr (indxMax > 0)
    {
        typedef decltype(spack<indxMax, seq...>{}) frst;
        constexpr int next = indxMax - 1;
        return get_seq17<next, spack, indxMax, seq...>();
    }
    else
    {
        return spack<indxMax, seq...>{};
    }
}

template <int indxMax, template <int...> class pack>
struct seq_pack
{
    typedef decltype(get_seq17<indxMax, pack>()) seq;
};


//creating a sequence wrapper
template <int ... seq>
struct seqpack {};

//usage
seq_pack<4, seqpack>::seq; //seqpack<0, 1, 2, 3, 4>
```

Though this implementation is easier to understand, it is preferable to use `std::make_index_sequence<Size>` as [Julius](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2615118/julius) has mentioned in the comments below.

Comment: Technically you could do this, yes. However, since C++14 you should just use `std::index_sequence` and friends. `std::make_index_sequence<N>` can be implemented using O(log(N)) instantiations. Moreover, it can be optimized to benefit from memoization. Special builtin compiler support could also allow O(1) for the `std` tools. You can only make it worse by using your O(N) `constexpr if` solution. Anyway, for understanding the concept (and with the proper warning) your answer is useful. (And it uses `int`, which is great.)