# Pass parameter pack to function with template deduction from return type

Tags: c++, parameter-passing, variadic-functions, rvalue-reference

I'm writing an object allocator that I'd like to call in the following way:

```
T result = factoryObject.construct(argA, argB, argC);
```

I currently have this design, which works...

```
class Factory {
  void* memPool_;
  
  template <typename Tret, typename... Args>
  Tret construct(Args&&... args) {
    Tret::methodA(std::forward<Args&&>(args));
    Tret::Tret(memPool_, std::forward<Args&&>(args);
  }
}
```

... as long as I call it with:

```
T result = factoryObject.construct<T>(argA, argB, argC);
```

I want to be able to do it without explicitly specifying `T`. `T` can get quite complex, and I need to use this factory inline in an initialiser list. I also need to use this in a constructor initialiser list, so I cannot call `auto result = factory.construct<T>()` (I simply need it to infer the return type based on what it is constructing).

I have tried inferring the type using the operator() trick (as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/2613010/4649183):

```
public:
    template <class T>
    operator T() { return T(); }
};

class GC {
public:
    static Allocator Allocate() { return Allocator(); }
};

int main() {
    int p = GC::Allocate();
}
```

... but this does not allow me to pass arguments (since  `operator()` cannot take arguments). I tried storing `Args&& args` as a tuple as a member of `Allocator`, repacking the tuple into a parameter pack and calling operator() separately using the logic proposed in the question of [Tuple to parameter pack](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36612596/4649183), but

1. That couldn't actually store references to parameters as far as I could tell (which makes sense because the compiler doesn't know that I'm not going to let the original args go out of scope)
2. The final solution was so complex that I just must've been going down the wrong path.

What can I do?

Comment: Are you missing a `return` in the first snippet of code?

Comment: *`T` can get quite complex* then give it an alias.

Comment: Also, `std::forward<Args&&>` is probably mean to be `std::forward<Args>`. Also you have unexpanded packs. Also, forwarding `args` twice in the same scope seems wrong.

Comment: Because of possible type-conversions, return type deduction isn't really that simple or always possible.

Comment: And if `T` can be complex, besides making an alias why not use `auto` type deduction? As in `auto result = factoryObject.construct<T_or_alias>(...)`?

Comment: "since  operator() cannot take arguments)" ? Do you mean the conversion operator? `operator()` can take arbitrary arguments. The conversion operator does not need the arguments

Comment: @Enlico indeed, this is a simplification of what I'm trying to do, admittedly my example won't build.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai I do indeed mean the conversion operator. I would need the conversion operator to take arguments if I were to abuse it in the way I described.

Comment: @OliverHawker no the conversion doesnt need the arguments. The point of the "trick" you refer to is that the conversion is triggered implicitly be the assignment. (actually the answer below explains this much better)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should have all pieces. Just have to assemble them correctly. Code should be similar to:

```
template <typename...Ts>
struct Constructor
{
    Constructor(void* memPool, Ts... args) :
        memPool{memPool},
        args{std::forward<Ts>(args)...}
    {}

    template <typename T>
    operator T() && {
        return std::apply(
            [this](auto&&... args) {
                T::methodA(std::forward<Args&&>(args));
                return T::T(memPool_, std::forward<Args&&>(args);
            },
            args);
    }

    void* memPool_;
    std::tuple<Ts...> args;
};

class Factory {
  void* memPool_;
  
  template <typename... Args>
  Constructor<Args&&...>  construct(Args&&... args) {
      return {memPool_, std::forward<Args>(args)...};
  }
};
```

Comment: This is fantastic, thank you! I half-understand how this works, but have modified it to test it with various combinations of l-value and r-values, and it works really well. I will work through and understand how it works, but this appears to solve my problem. Thank you so much for the quick reply!

Comment: @NathanOliver: `Constructor<Args&&...>` already fix `Ts` with lvalue/rvalue references.

Comment: Aha, that's what I was missing.