How to convert a tuple of types to a tuple of class template instantiations, using the tuple types as template arguments
Consider the following types.
template<int data_>
struct CompileTimeData{ static constexpr int data = data_; };

template<int data>
struct S{};

In C++17, how does one convert a tuple of different CompileTimeData instances into a tuple of different S instances? The data should be used as template argument for S.
std::tuple<CompileTimeData<4>, CompileTimeData<2>> ---> std::tuple<S<4>, S<2>>
In practice, CompileTimeData will have multiple integers as template parameters, each of which must be passed to S.
My use case would look like this:
template<class DataTupleA, class DataTupleB>
struct X{
   using TupleOfS_A = ... // convert from DataTupleA
   using TupleOfS_B = ... // convert from DataTupleB
};

X<
   std::tuple<CompileTimeData<4>, CompileTimeData<2>>,
   std::tuple<CompileTimeData<3>, CompileTimeData<5>>
> x;



this question may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36612596/21691539. It may help to convert your tuple to a pack of int that you will use, in turn to make a tuple of S.

@Oersted I edited my question. It should be possible to have multiple parameters in CompileTimeData that must be passed to S.

is the type and number of parameters fixed?

You can create a traits for that:
template <typename Tuple>
struct myTransform;

template <int... Ns>
struct myTransform<std::tuple<CompileTimeData<Ns>...>>
{
    using type = std::tuple<S<Ns>...>;
};

Demo
You might have a more generic transform as follow:
template <typename Tuple, template <typename> class Transformer>
struct TupleTransform;

template <typename... Ts, template <typename> class Transformer>
struct TupleTransform<std::tuple<Ts...>, Transformer>
{
    using type = std::tuple<typename Transformer<Ts>::type...>;
};

and then
template <typename> struct CompileTimeData2S;

template <int N/*, ..*/>
struct CompileTimeData2S<CompileTimeData<N/*, ..*/>>
{
    using type = S<N /*, ..*/>;
};

Demo

I edited my question. It should be possible to have multiple parameters in CompileTimeData that must be passed to S

Avoid to change question in a way which invalidate existing answer (asking another question might be better then) (edited to take into account your extra edit.
