# How do I reverse the order of the integers in a `std::integer_sequence<int, 4, -5, 7, -3>`?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, constexpr, template-meta-programming

Sometimes I want to reverse the values in an `index_sequence` and use the result to reverse the values in something *tuple-like*, like in this illustration which reverses the values in a `constexpr` `std::array` at compile time.

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <cstdint>
#include <utility>

namespace detail {
template <class T, std::size_t N, std::size_t... I>
    constexpr std::array<T, N> rev_arr_helper(const std::array<T, N>& arr,
                                              std::index_sequence<I...>) {
        return {arr[sizeof...(I) - I - 1]...};

        //     {arr[4-0-1], arr[4-1-1], arr[4-2-1], arr[4-3-1]}
        //     =>
        //     {arr[3], arr[2], arr[1], arr[0]}
    }
}  // namespace detail

template <class T, std::size_t N>
constexpr std::array<T, N> rev_arr(const std::array<T, N>& arr) {
    return detail::rev_arr_helper(arr, std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}

int main() {
    constexpr std::array<int, 4> arr{11, 22, 33, 44};
    constexpr auto rev = rev_arr(arr);    
    static_assert(rev[0] == 44 && rev[1] == 33 && rev[2] == 22 && rev[3] == 11, "");
}
```

Now, this approach does not work for *any* `integer_sequence`, like the one in the title. It only works for those ordered `0, 1, 2, ..., N-1` and I would like to be able to make this compile using C++14:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

int main() {
    std::integer_sequence<int, 4, -5, 7, -3> iseq;
    std::integer_sequence<int, -3, 7, -5, 4> itarget;

    auto irev = reverse_sequence(iseq);

    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(irev), decltype(itarget)>::value, "");
}
```

How can that be done?

---

Here's a somewhat related Q&A collected from the comments:
[How do I reverse the order of element types in a tuple type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17178075/how-do-i-reverse-the-order-of-element-types-in-a-tuple-type)

Comment: somewhat related https://stackoverflow.com/q/17178075/4117728

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Of course that didn't show up when I searched to see if it was worth writing a wiki Q&A about this :-) I'll read it through, thanks.

Comment: its about tuples though. Actually I only mentioned it because of this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/26317988/4117728. Didnt think it through but it might be applicable here

Comment: and most answers there seem to rely heavily on recursion :/

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number So many good answers to read.  I _did_ search quite a lot before posting (or so I thought) :-) Yes, some use recursion and some look somewhat similar to what I came up with as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution that doesn't use `std::tuple` is to convert to an `std::array` and access the corresponding indices with the help of `std::make_index_sequence`.

```cpp
namespace detail {
    template<typename T, T... N, std::size_t... Indices>
    constexpr auto reverse_sequence_helper(std::integer_sequence<T, N...> sequence,
                                           std::index_sequence<Indices...>) {
        constexpr auto array = std::array<T, sizeof...(N)> { N... };
        return std::integer_sequence<T, array[sizeof...(Indices) - Indices - 1]...>();
    }
}
template<typename T, T... N>
constexpr auto reverse_sequence(std::integer_sequence<T, N...> sequence) {
    return detail::reverse_sequence_helper(sequence,
                                           std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(N)>());
}
```

---

if C++20 is available, it can be reduced to this function with the help of templated lambdas:

```cpp
template<typename T, T... N>
constexpr auto reverse_sequence(std::integer_sequence<T, N...> sequence) {
    constexpr auto array = std::array { N... };
 
    auto make_sequence = [&]<typename I, I... Indices>(std::index_sequence<Indices...>) {
        return std::integer_sequence<T, array[sizeof...(Indices) - Indices - 1]...>();
    };
    return make_sequence(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(N)>());
}
```

Comment: Just edited to make it fit in the narrow code box :) Thanks! This looks very nice!

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to create a `std::index_sequence` to be able to simulate using the subscript operator to access the values in your `integer_sequence`. By putting the sequence of integers, `I...`, in a `std::tuple` one can use `std::get<>` to extract the value at a certain position in the `tuple`. We want something similar to `I[pos]...` (had it worked) which is what we get with:

```
std::get<pos>( std::tuple<decltype(I)...>{I...} )...
```

- Sidenote: `<decltype(I)...>` above is needed to make it work in C++14. In C++17 and later, one can simply do:

  ```
  std::get<pos>( std::tuple{I...} )...
  ```

Putting that in place makes it very similar to reversing the elements in an array:

```cpp
#include <cstddef>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

namespace detail {
    template <class T, T... I, std::size_t... J>
    constexpr auto rev_helper(std::integer_sequence<T, I...>, std::index_sequence<J...>)
    {
        return
            std::integer_sequence<T,
                std::get<sizeof...(J) - J - 1>(std::tuple<decltype(I)...>{I...})...>{};
//                                                                     /    \
//       index_sequence: └─── 3, 2, 1, 0 ───┘       integer_sequence: 4, -5, 7, -3
    }
}  // namespace detail
```

This will with the example `integer_sequence<int, 4, -5, 7, -3>` then be expanded to the type:

```
std::integer_sequence<int,
    std::get<3>(std::tuple<int,int,int,int>{4, -5, 7, -3}), // -3
    std::get<2>(std::tuple<int,int,int,int>{4, -5, 7, -3}), //  7
    std::get<1>(std::tuple<int,int,int,int>{4, -5, 7, -3}), // -5
    std::get<0>(std::tuple<int,int,int,int>{4, -5, 7, -3})  //  4
>
```

which is the same as the target type `std::integer_sequence<int, -3, 7, -5, 4>`.

The front-end for the helper function just takes the original `integer_sequence` and passes it on to the helper with an `index_sequence`:

```
template <class T, T... I>
constexpr auto reverse_sequence(std::integer_sequence<T, I...> seq) {
    return detail::rev_helper(seq, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(I)>{});
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/qnvcW6ra6)